# Notepad++, maximum number of opened files

Tags: notepad++

I love Notepad++, but I always forget to close my opened files, when I finally decide to close them I have tons of tabs to close.

I was wondering if there is a way to set the number of maximum opened files, so it will force me to close some files when reaching this limit.

Comment: If you have looked through the default options, and there is no option to set the number of files you can have open, you will have to write a plugin to add this funtionality to notepad++

Comment: Did look, did not find anything, I have no time to write such a plugin, with a bit of luck maybe there is a plugin out there which can perform what I desire.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on an open tab and choose between the options

> Close all but this
>
> Close all to left
>
> Close all to right

This is kind of a work around and not a solution